# How to overlay multiple TA in new plot using quantmod?

Tags: r, quantmod

We can plot candle stick chart using chart series function `chartSeries(Cl(PSEC))` I have created some custom values (**I1**,**I2** and **I3**) which I want to plot together(overlay) outside the candle stick pattern. I have used `addTA()` for this purpose

```
chartSeries(Cl(PSEC)), TA="addTA(I1,col=2);addTA(I2,col=3);addTA(I3,col=4)")
```

The problem is that it plots four plots for **Cl(PSEC),I1,I2** and **I3** separately instead of two plots which I want **Cl(PSEC)** and **(I1,I2,I3)**

**EDITED**

For clarity I am giving a sample code with I1, I2 and I3 variable created for this purpose

```
library(quantmod)
PSEC=getSymbols("PSEC",auto.assign=F)
price=Cl(PSEC)
I1=SMA(price,3)
I2=SMA(price,10)
I3=SMA(price,15)
chartSeries(price, TA="addTA(I1,col=2);addTA(I2,col=3);addTA(I3,col=4)")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option which preserves largely your original code.
You can obtain the desired result using the option `on=2` for each TA after the first:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("PSEC")
price <- Cl(PSEC)
I1 <- SMA(price,3)
I2 <- SMA(price,10)
I3 <- SMA(price,15)
chartSeries(price, TA=list("addTA(I1, col=2)", "addTA(I2, col=4, on=2)",
                           "addTA(I3, col=5, on=2)"), subset = "last 6 months")
```

[image]

If you want to overlay the price and the SMAs in one chart, you can use the option `on=1` for each TA.

Thanks to @hvollmeier who made me realize with his answer that I had misunderstood your question in the previous version of my answer.

PS: Note that several options are described in `?addSMA()`, including `with.col` which can be used to select a specific column of the time series (Cl is the default column).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you want the 3 SMAs in a SUBPLOT and NOT in your main chart window.You can do the following using `newTA`.
Using your data:

```
PSEC=getSymbols("PSEC",auto.assign=F)
price=Cl(PSEC)
```

Now plotting a 10,30,50 day SMA in a window below the main window:

```
chartSeries(price['2016'])
newSMA <- newTA(SMA, Cl, on=NA)
newSMA(10)
newSMA(30,on=2)
newSMA(50,on=2)
```

The key is the argument `on`. Use `on = NA` in defining your new TA function, because the default value for`on` is 1, which is the main window. `on = NA` plots in a new window. Then plot the remaining SMAs to the same window as the first SMA. Style the colours etc.to your liking :-).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider solving this task using plotting with the newer quantmod charts in the `quantmod` package (`chart_Series` as opposed to `chartSeries`).

Pros: 
-The plots look cleaner and better (?)
-have more flexibility via editing the `pars` and `themes` options to `chart_Series` (see other examples here on SO for the basics of things you can do with `pars` and `themes`)
Cons:
-Not well documented.

```
PSEC=getSymbols("PSEC",auto.assign=F)
price=Cl(PSEC)
chart_Series(price, subset = '2016')
add_TA(SMA(price, 10))
add_TA(SMA(price, 30), on = 2, col = "green")
add_TA(SMA(price, 50), on = 2, col = "red")


# Make plot all at once (this approach is useful in shiny applications):
print(chart_Series(price, subset = '2016', TA = 'add_TA(SMA(price, 10), yaxis = list(0, 10));
add_TA(SMA(price, 30), on = 2, col = "purple"); add_TA(SMA(price, 50), on = 2, col = "red")'))
```

[image]