# How to add simple moving average to multiple candlestick charts using quantmode

Tags: r, quantmod, candlestick-chart

I am following up several stocks prices. Thanks to Vincent Zoonekynd (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1129973/vincent-zoonekynd), I was able to plot multiple charts in a page.
Now, I want to add 20 ,and 200 days single moving average line to each chart but the chart is repeated.
My code is

```
library(quantmod)
end <- Sys.Date()
start <- end - 365
stocks <- c("GOOG", "INTC", "AAPL")
stocksts <- list()
i <- 1
for(stock in stocks){
stocksts[[i]] <- getSymbols(stock
, src = "yahoo"
, from = start
, to = end
,auto.assign =  FALSE
, return.class = "xts")  
i <- i+1
}
par(mfcol=c(3,1), oma=c(1,1,0,0), mar=c(1,1,1,0), tcl=-0.1, mgp=c(0,0,0))
for (i in 1:length(stocksts)){
chartSeries(na.omit(scale(stocksts[[i]]))
,"candlesticks"
,name = names(df)
,TA = NULL 
, layout = NULL
, yrange = c(-3,3) 
)
addSMA(n = 20, col = "green")
addSMA(n = 200, col = "red")
}
```

Would you please advise how could I print candlestick and SMA charts avoiding repetition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for, given the framework you set up,

I recommend you look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37873283/9555388, this may help you improve the set up...

1: The set up

```
library(quantmod)
end <- Sys.Date()
start <- end - 365
stocks <- c("GOOG", "INTC", "AAPL")
stocksts <- list()
i <- 1
for(stock in stocks){
  stocksts[[i]] <- getSymbols(stock
                              , src = "yahoo"
                              , from = start
                              , to = end
                              ,auto.assign =  FALSE
                              , return.class = "xts")  
  i <- i+1
}
```

2: The new method of adding the SMA and plotting the data all at once

```
par(mfcol=c(3,1), oma=c(1,1,0,0), mar=c(1,1,1,0), tcl=-0.1, mgp=c(0,0,0))
for (i in 1:length(stocksts)){
  price=Cl(stocksts[[i]])
  newSMA <- newTA(SMA, Cl, on=NA)
  print(chart_Series(price, TA = 'add_TA(SMA(price, 20), on = 1, col = "green"); add_TA(SMA(price, 200), on = 1, col = "red")', yrange = c(-3,3)))

}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, although I have made some changes to method 2 in order to plot candlesticks instead of closing price

Comment: @RAFAELANTONIOVENTURA Ah yes, what was the change? Then I'll edit the answer, then you can accept if you think it answered your question?